# running js code thats domain locked

Tags: javascript, apache, security, docker

i was wondering if its possible to run js code that is set to only run on `localhost`

is there a way to maybe spin up a docker container with a hostname of `localhost` and have the js code execute from it as its being served from the web?

`so www.sample.com loads a site -> /js/* -> proxys to docker loading js code assuming the hostname of the docker container which would be localhost`

or maybe there is another intuitive way to achive this?

update:

in the end its to trick the js code to think its being loaded from `localhost:80` instead of `www.sample.com:80`

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your question, but perhaps ngrok can help you out here. It allows you to tunnel requests to a locally running server. https://ngrok.com/

Comment: @Eli you can do it if you adding the good directive to your vhost and httpd.config to add SSI rules but that will be a intranet access.

Comment: would this "trick" the js code to think its being loaded on "localhost:80" and not www.sameple.com?

Comment: Your question is still a bit unclear. If you mean that the js code is using `window.location.href` then it would see what is in the browser and not your `localhost`. If your browser is `localhost` and your load JS from any place it would get url as localhost in the code